# MySQL Like query logic

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a table like this;

```
|----------------------|
|field1    |   field2  |
|----------------------|
|1,2,3,0   |   area 1  |
|5,7,8     |   area 2  |
|10,6      |   area 3  |
|----------------------|
```

I have a query like this :

`select * from areas where field1 like '%0%'`

This query giving me `area 1` and `area 3`. But I want to get only `area 1` because 0 is only in `area 1`. Also I tried `field1 like '0%'` but it gave me no row.

Comment: try this `field1 like '%,0%'`

Comment: @OSSCubeSolution That would only work if every `field1` started with a comma

Comment: @OSSCubeSolution I tried this but first number hasn't got comma before

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt yes you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This `Query`:

```
select * from areas where field1 like '%,0%'
```

Thanks **[OSSCube Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1035257/osscube-solution)**

**EDIT**

```
select * from areas where field1 like '0%' or field1 like '%,0%'
```

Comment: That would only work if every field1 started with a comma. Might work in this specific case but in other cases it won't work.

Comment: So you're giving him code of which you know that it will eventually break? -1

Answer (score 5):

[Normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your table. It's the only good way to solve this problem.

Comment: +1 for normalizing. And if you REALLY can't change the table you can use `FIND_IN_SET` to search CSV fields.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    select * from areas where field1 like '%,0%'  or 
                              field1 like '%,0,%' or 
                              field1 like '0,%'
```

Comment: You Don't need this <s> field1 like '%,0,%' or </s>